# Use a dataframes column to select rows from another frame in the same order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

Need some pandas jump start here:

Consider two data frames `A` and `B`. Both contain a column `id` with identifier values:

```
A: id     valA
   8      ?
   2      ?
   4      ?

B: id     valB    valC   
   1      ?       ?      
   4      ?       ?      
   3      ?       ?      
   8      ?       ?      
   2      ?       ?
```

I need a version of dataframe `B` which contains only the rows that contain the identifiers from `A[id]`, in exactly the same order as in `A`. That is:

```
B': id     valB     valC
    8      ?        ?
    2      ?        ?
    4      ?        ?
```

I assume this is a basic operation in pandas, but it seems I am missing the vocabulary to google it right now.

I've tried

```
B.loc[B['id'].isin(A['id'])]
```

but that doesn't seem to be the solution - the column `id` in the result doesn't have the same order of values as in  `A`.

Comment: This is called `reindex_axis` but, unlike your question above you mention in one of your comments `id` may not be unique, which will be incompatible with your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
In [92]: A.merge(B)
Out[92]:
   id valA valB valC
0   8    ?    ?    ?
1   2    ?    ?    ?
2   4    ?    ?    ?
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way.  `how='inner'` is the default for the merge method.